# How to get Word icons displayed properly in MS Office 2016?

Tags: ms-office

I upgraded my MS Office 2013 to 2016 and since then all docx files haven't had the icons properly displayed.
What I've tried so far:

1. select file->open with->select Word
2. select file->more applications->selecting Word.exe from the folder
3. open new Word file ->open saved docx file.

None of these works. I've been beating my brains out trying to figure out how to get the Word icons displayed properly.
I use MS Office Professional Plus 2016 (32-bit version) on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Did you try: [Repair an Office application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)  ?

Comment: Yep, to no avail.

Comment: Please check this: [How to fix: DOCX files not showing Word icon in Explorer.](https://www.wintips.org/how-to-fix-docx-files-not-showing-word-icon-in-explorer/)